Why, in Windows, does CloseHandle hang until FlushFileBuffers is done?
I've been developing a Windows program that has a data buffer that must be flushed (synced) to disk while simultaneously being read. To do this, I used two threads, one that flushes the data using the FlushFileBuffers call, and another that opens the file, reads it using ReadFile (synchronously), and closes it. It appears that the reading thread is blocked during the CloseHandle library call until the FlushFileBuffers call completes, serializing the two operations.
I would like the file close operation to be performed in non-blocking fashion at the same time as the disk flush. Since this is a multi-threaded program, and the two threads do not seem to have any dependencies between them, I'm not sure why there should be any waiting.
I have created a stripped-down example to illustrate the problem, with error handling omitted for concision:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

volatile int done_a = 0;
volatile int done_b = 0;
unsigned long long file_size;

long unsigned int reader_func(void *unused) {
    DWORD err;
    HANDLE h;

    srand(time(NULL));

    puts("reading randomly in file");
    unsigned char buf;
    while (!done_a) {
        clock_t begin = clock();
        h = CreateFileA("test.bin",
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);
        unsigned long long randVal = (((unsigned long long)rand() << 60) |
                                    ((unsigned long long)rand() << 45) |
                                    ((unsigned long long)rand() << 30) |
                                    ((unsigned long long)rand() << 15) |
                                    ((unsigned long long)rand() << 0)) % file_size;
        printf("reading at %llu\n", randVal);
        SetFilePointerEx(h, (LARGE_INTEGER){.QuadPart=randVal}, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
        ReadFile(h, &buf, 1, NULL, NULL);

        puts("closing file handle");
        CloseHandle(h);

        double time_spent = (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("read took %f\n", time_spent);

        Sleep(250);
    }

    done_b = 1;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *endptr;
    if (argc > 1)
        file_size = strtoull(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
    else
        return 1;

    // Open file
    DWORD err;
    HANDLE h = CreateFileA("test.bin",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    // Size file to given size
    SetFilePointerEx(h, (LARGE_INTEGER){.QuadPart=file_size}, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    SetEndOfFile(h);

    SetFilePointerEx(h, (LARGE_INTEGER){0}, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    // Write some data to file
    puts("writing to file");
    char buf[4096];
    memset(buf, 0xa5, 4096);
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < file_size; i += 4096)
        WriteFile(h, buf, 4096, NULL, NULL);

    // spawn thread to continuously read from block
    puts("spawning reader thread");
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, reader_func, NULL, 0, NULL);

    Sleep(250);

    // FlushFileBuffers
    puts("flushing file buffers");
    clock_t begin = clock();
    FlushFileBuffers(h);
    double time_spent = (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("FlushFileBuffers took %f to finish\n", time_spent);

    // signal completion
    puts("done");
    done_a = 1;

    CloseHandle(h);

    while (!done_b);
    puts("done");

    DeleteFileA("test.bin");

    return 0;
}

If one runs the above code with a large argument like a.exe 1073741824 (depending on your disk write speed you may need to make this number lesser or greater), they will see that the CloseHandle call takes approximately as long as the FlushFileBuffers call, since it waits for it to complete before returning. I used SysInternals Process Monitor to observe the behavior.
I have tested this under Windows 10 and 11, using an HDD and SDD, and the problem persists in all cases. Even Wine in Linux shows this behavior. The expected behavior is: CloseHandle does not wait and returns instantly. I have also observed this blocking behavior with other library calls, such as CreateFile and ReadFile, but these proved harder to reproduce.
Operating System: Windows 10
Compiler: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc 13
Disk: SK hynix BC511 NVMe SSD

Check ReadFile's lpOverlapped (last) argument: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile#synchronization-and-file-position which is exactly what you need. I only have a Python example: [SO]: win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW doesn't find all moved files (@CristiFati's answer).

@CristiFati Wouldn't overlapped mode just make ReadFile return before the completion? What effect would it have on the time taken to complete the read operation?

@IanAbbott: You're correct (it's the function call that doesn't block, not the read operation itself). In addition to my previous comment check CreateFile's dwFlagsAndAttributes argument: FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH.

I can't seem to reproduce the problem on my Windows 10 system writing to SATA SSD or HDD with NTFS file system. For example, when writing 1000000000 bytes on the SSD, the ReadFile calls usually took 0.000000 seconds and very occasionally 0.001000 seconds, so probably less than 1 millisecond, and FlushFileBuffers took 2.115000 seconds.

@CristiFati I considered using overlapped I/O, but I'm not sure that would fix the problem, as it would only enable the call to return right away, but not speed up its completion. I figure whatever problem is causing the serialization in the synchronous case would affect the asynchronous case as well.

@Ian Abbott Thanks for testing it, that is the behavior I am expecting to see. I think the problem may be something to do with my setup then. Can you elaborate a little bit more about how you ran it? Which compiler you used, did you run from Command Prompt or something else?

It was the mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc compiler from MSYS2, running in both a Bash shell in Windows Terminal, and in a CMD shell in the old Windows console, both on Windows 10.

@Conexn Indeed it has block in visual studio 2022. https://i.sstatic.net/4xuqlGLj.png I'll figure it out.

@Conexn FlushFileBuffers always block Readfile before Writefile. I think it normal. FlushFileBuffers make sure Writefile succeed and all the data has been written to the disk. If not, Writefile and Readfile are no longer synchronous, but asynchronous. Readfile will return 0.

@Torrecto-MSFT I can understand why it would block WriteFile, but shouldn't ReadFile should be able to go forward unimpeded?. Also, I see accounts from people who do not see the behavior I do, which makes me think it is possible. Also, you may need to increase the value of the argument to recreate the behavior; the image you linked used a really small size.

I can't repeat either (Win10 64-bit).  I get 29-48us per read and flush takes 1.5s on a 100MB file.

I can repeat the issue if I pass a main's handle to the thread instead of opening a separate handle.  The handle is created in synchronous mode so all actions on the handle are serialized.  In that case, creating ansychronous handles (pass an OVERLAPPED parameter) then waiting on the overlapped event after each read/write/flush allows them to be processed in parallel similar to using separate synchronous handles.

I had difficulty myself reproducing the ReadFile blocking on other machines, so I looked at my original problem again and found that the hang was on CloseHandle, rather than ReadFile. This seems to block (takes as long as the FlushFileBuffers call) on every machine I've tested. I've edited the post and provided new test code to reflect this more specific problem. Hopefully someone on here will be able to reproduce it now.

I mean, that kinda makes sense? How is the kernel supposed to close a file handle while any operation is still pending on it?

@nneonneo This is a close on a different file handle than the one the FlushFileBuffers is using on a separate thread.

@Conexn maybe it's worth attaching ETW to your program to see what kernel-level functions are blocking CloseHandle.

@nneonneo I haven't done that, but ProcMon tells me that the driver calls that correspond to CloseHandle and FlushFileBuffers are IRP_MJ_CLEANUP and IRP_MJ_FLUSH_BUFFERS (both take a long time). I'm not really a Windows developer, so I'm a bit fearful of looking into the kernel, but I'll do it if necessary.

Try this tool for collecting and analyzing ETW traces: https://github.com/google/UIforETW. It doesn't require a deep understanding of the kernel, and is quite easy to use from what I've heard.
